# OSGI Declarative Service Injection After Activation

Tags: java, osgi

How can we make sure that all dependencies are injected before `activate()` call?

```
    private IMyDependency aInstance, bInstance, cInstance;

    public void setDependency(IMyDependency depInstance) {

        Bundle depBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(depInstance.getClass());

        logger.debug("Dependency {} from bundle {} retrieved", depInstance, depBundle.getSymbolicName());

        if (A_BUNDLE_NAME.equals(depBundle.getSymbolicName())) {
            aInstance = depInstance;
        } else if (B_BUNDLE_NAME.equals(depBundle.getSymbolicName())) {
            bInstance = depInstance;
        } else if (C_BUNDLE_NAME.equals(depBundle.getSymbolicName())) {
            cInstance = depInstance;
        } else {
            logger.error("Dependency {} from unknown bundle {}", depInstance, depBundle);
        }
    }

    public void activate() {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(aInstance);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(bInstance);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(cInstance);
        //...
    }
```

There are multiple instances of IMyDependency, and the dependency cardinality is `0..n`.

Problem is, `setDependency()` is sometimes called after `activate()` method. A workaround is to change start levels of the dependent bundles, but we really don't want to touch configuration.

Comment: You want to activate the component only if all three dependencies are available? Why do not you create three separate references in the component?

Comment: Not exactly. I want framework to activate the component after all dependencies are injected. And there already are three separate references in the component.

Comment: Based on your sample code, you need three separate STATIC reference with MANDATORY cardinality instead of having one 0..n reference. It is a very bad practice to wire OSGi services based on the fact from which bundle they come. Also, see the minimum-cardinality option that came in the new specification of Declarative Services (I do not know if that is already implemented in the new SCR project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Balazs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354879/balazs-zsoldos)' comment, I was able to change `0..n` dependencies into 3 explicit `1..1` dependencies:

```
<reference bind="setDependencyA" cardinality="1..1" interface="com.example.IMyDependency" name="DepA" policy="static" target="(dependencyType=A)"/>
<reference bind="setDependencyB" cardinality="1..1" interface="com.example.IMyDependency" name="DepB" policy="static" target="(dependencyType=B)"/>
<reference bind="setDependencyC" cardinality="1..1" interface="com.example.IMyDependency" name="DepC" policy="static" target="(dependencyType=C)"/>
```

Dependent class:

```
    public void setDependencyA(IMyDependency depInstance) {
        aInstance = depInstance;
    }

    public void setDependencyB(IMyDependency depInstance) {
        bInstance = depInstance;
    }

    public void setDependencyC(IMyDependency depInstance) {
        cInstance = depInstance;
    }
```

And I also had to change the dependencies' activation (unfortunately dependencies do not use DS):

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<>();
    props.put("dependencyType", "A");
    srvReg = context.registerService(IMyDependency.class.getName(), myInstance, props);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And now for the whole component with annotations:

```
 @Component public class MyComponent {

   @Reference(target="(dependencyType=A)") IMyDependency aInstance;
   @Reference(target="(dependencyType=B)") IMyDependency bInstance;
   @Reference(target="(dependencyType=C)") IMyDependency cInstance;


   @Activate public void activate() {
    // all guaranteed set
   }
}
```

The instance component:

```
@Component public class MyDependency implements IMyDependency {
   ...
}
```

And you should use [configuration](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/osgi.enroute.configurer.api.html) to create the 3 instances.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is kind of a plugin system. So you know the interface but you do not know how many impls are there but you want to make sure all are loaded until you load.

This is not so easy in OSGi. In fact an additional service may come at runtime. So one solution is to simply adapt to all changes of the services. In some cases this is not enough though.

For example I had a case where I wanted to supply security plugins to my application. It would not be acceptable that my bundle starts without that security plugin but it should be configurable.

So what I did was to give each plugin a name using an OSGi property and in the plugin mechanism I allowed to list the names of all plugins to load in a config pid. The mechanism made sure that the main application only started when all named plugins are present. Unfortunately such a mechanism is not built into DS but you can implement it using the bind and unbind methods.

Answer (score 0):

Plain OSGi is very firm on managing dependencies. You should be explicit about your dependency chain. You can get more dynamic by implementing a smart service tracker which delays your initialisation until all your dependencies are available. However, I suggest you using declarative services to avoid old fashioned dependency injection.

Comment: "However, I suggest you using declarative services to avoid old fashioned dependency injection.": Based on the title of the question, I guess b10y already uses Declarative Services.